# OpenSearchServer MSG Parser

Tags: regex, open-search-server

I'm using v OpenSearchServer 1.5.13  and trying to setup index for parsing MSG files on Network share and using MSG Parser.

I configured the MSG parameters to index email_display_from, email_display_to and creation_date to Index fields From,To,Date

I'm basically trying to use the email fields Date, From and To using the JSON API but see the results always end up empty.

```
 {  "fieldName": "Header"  },
 {  "fieldName": "To" }, 
 {  "fieldName": "From"   }
```

Also the regular expression for email_display_to looks like `\bTo.*\.com\b`.
Can you please let me know if the setup is wrong?

What is the regular expression to get the above index working for MSG file?

I want these fields to be displayed in default renderer view and the JSON API results.

Comment: When you say the result is empty, is it not creating an index document in OSS?  Or is a document created but with the fields empty?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you means "CreationDate" and not "Header" (there is no header extraction in the MSG Parser).

Here is the check-list:

1. The fields **CreationDate**, **To** and **From** are created in the schema with the **stored** attribute checked.
2. The FieldMap panel of the **MSG Parser** includes the links between your fields (CreationDate, To and From) and the parser fields **email_display_from**, **email_display_to** and **creation_date**.
3. In the **Search Query**, you added the fields "CreationDate", "To" and "From" in the **Returned Fields** list.
4. In the **Renderer** you also have added the fields "CreationDate", "To" and "From".

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for the response. I did settings exactly as above and below is the call from POSTMAN `code ` {  
   "query":"Test",
   "rows":500,
   "returnedFields":[ 
      "fileName",
      "url","fileSystemDate","CreationDate","To","From"
   ]
} `code`  but the results are still empty  ` {
                    "fieldName": "CreationDate"
                },
                {
                    "fieldName": "To"
                },
                {
                    "fieldName": "From"
                }`code`

Comment: Also here is the regex I'm using for extracting the  To Fields: \bTo.*\.com\b and from also \bFrom.*\.com\b .Not sure if this is correct.I'm a novice in regular expressions and assuming that's the heart to  extract these values.Appreciate your help and assistance